# Click on HTML table and get row number (with Javascript, not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row

I would like to know how to click on a button in an HTML table and get the row and column number returned to me:  For example, with the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

How would I use JavaScript to click on the first button in the second row and have it tell me that I clicked on the first cell in the second row?  Does each button need to have a unique id, or not?

Comment: Rows have [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex). and cells have [`cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement). You can use them [like so ...](http://jsfiddle.net/eoemydb5/)

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```js
function  getId(element) {
    alert("row" + element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex + 
    " - column" + element.parentNode.cellIndex);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="getId(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could easily add this to the TD <td onclick=getId(this)> and drop one of the parentNode functions to not use the buttons.

Comment: I try "element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex" but it returns undefined

Comment: Superman...... I got so many solutions by jQuery. I wanted in Javascript. GOT IT.....

Answer (score 11):

Most generic version of @Gremash js function

```
function  getId(element) {
    alert("row" + element.closest('tr').rowIndex + 
    " -column" + element.closest('td').cellIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
alert(document.getElementById("yourTableId").childNodes[1].childElementCount);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.