# how to dynamically increment input control...??? (java script)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a `for` loop to copy the content of the table n times. Unfortunately, the code I mentioned below works only for the 1st table only.

How can I make it work for every tables? Please suggest some solutions for this. (I am a beginner)

```css
function copy() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
    document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("Name3").value;
    document.getElementById("Name4").value = text2;
}
```

```html
<tr><td rowspan="3" style="height:100px;">
Name  <input type="text" name="Emp name"  placeholder="enter your name"  id="Name1"/><br>
ID    <input type="id" name="Emp Id" placeholder="enter id" id="Name3" > </td>

<td style="height:150px;">

<input type="button" value="Get data" onclick="copy();"/>
<label for="text"> Name : <input type="text" id="Name2"></label>
<label for="text"> ID   : <input type="id" id="Name4"></label> 

</td></tr>
```

Comment: Beacuse id attribute should be unique for each element . you should not make duplicate it .

Comment: oh.suggest me some solution buddy.

Comment: is it okay to use jquery ? . @Bala_Poyyamoli

Comment: will u please help in javascript..??@JYoThI

Comment: okay wait minute

Comment: first thing you need to change all id to class name and follow this link . you will get some idea how to do it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042140/click-on-html-table-and-get-row-number-with-javascript-not-jquery

Comment: thank u buddy.i ll come back after trying it

Comment: it's easy to do with jquery traverse . but im not familiar with javascript node traverse . @Bala_Poyyamoli

Comment: sry to say this.i think that example doesn't match in my scenario or I didn't understand that properly.

Comment: yup, give me in jquery buddy.i ll try to convert it to js.

Comment: sure i will give @Bala_Poyyamoli

Comment: can you check my below answer @Bala_Poyyamoli

Comment: please wait a minute @JYoThI

Comment: yes, it works.thank you so much @JYoThi

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @Bala_Poyyamoli

Comment: yup, i did it buddy.

Answer (score 1):

**1st** : Because `id attribute` should be unique for each element . you should not make duplicate it . you should use `class name` instead of id .

As per your comment i give some example in jquery .

```js
$(document).on('click','.get_data',function(){
 
    name1_val =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.Name1').val();
    name3_val =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.Name3').val();
    
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.Name2').val(name1_val);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.Name4').val(name3_val);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3" style="height:100px;">
Name  <input type="text" name="Emp name"  placeholder="enter your name"  class="Name1"/><br>
ID    <input type="id" name="Emp Id" placeholder="enter id" class="Name3" > </td><br>

<td  style="height:150px;">

<input type="button" value="Get data" class="get_data" /><br>
<label for="text"> Name : <input type="text" class="Name2"></label><br>
<label for="text"> ID   : <input type="id" class="Name4"></label> 

</td></tr> <br>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3" style="height:100px;">
Name  <input type="text" name="Emp name"  placeholder="enter your name"  class="Name1"/><br>
ID    <input type="id" name="Emp Id" placeholder="enter id" class="Name3" > </td>

<td  style="height:150px;">

<input type="button" value="Get data" class="get_data" /><br>
<label for="text"> Name : <input type="text" class="Name2"></label><br>
<label for="text"> ID   : <input type="id" class="Name4"></label> 

</td></tr>
</tbody>
```